# How to list directory contents with a sas token for directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure

In a react project I am trying to list all the files in blob storage using a sas token created for the given directory. My understanding is I need to create a DataLakeFileSystemClient but I only have a url for the directory and a DataLakeDirectoryClient and somehow need to create the DataLakeFileSystemClient.

The url passed is something along the lines of: [https://myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydirectory{sastoken}](https://myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydirectory%7Bsastoken%7D)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this, although I don't know if it's the best way.
To get the directory client to a FileSystem client I wrote a helper method

```js
const getFileSystemClient = (directoryClient: DataLakeDirectoryClient) => {
    const url = new URL(directoryClient.url);
    url.pathname = directoryClient.fileSystemName;
    return new DataLakeFileSystemClient(url.toString());
}
```

To list directories I use the following code

```js
const fsClient = getFileSystemClient(directoryClient);
for await(const path of fsClient.listPaths({path: directoryClient.name})) {
    console.log(path.name);
}
```